# How to display the selected file name in the ListControl in MFC in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have created a grid function using list control. There are two columns in the list. Data and NAME.

The user should select a file; and the data inside the file should be diplayed in first column "DATA" and file name should be displayed in the 2nd column "NAME". 
I have written a code but nothing is appearing in the list

```
CFileFind finder;
bool bFound;
CString filename = "C:\\ Location\\*.txt";
bFound = finder.FindFile(filename);

if(bFound) 
{

   while(bFound) 
   {
        bFound = finder.FindNextFile();
        if(bFound)
        {
            m_List.AddString(finder.GetFileName()); //This is where the actual data is added 
        }
   }
   CStdioFile files;
   CFileException exp;
   CString strLine;  

   if (files.Open(filename, CFile::modeRead, &exp))
   {
      while(files.ReadString(strLine)){}
   }
}
void CuserspecificationDlg::InsertItems()
{
       HWND hWnd = ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_LIST1);
       // Set the LVCOLUMN structure with the required 
       // column information
         ..
         .. 
         SetCell(hWnd,out,1,1);   // where out is the Cstring variable for edit control  
}
```

What can be the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see a tutorial on how to use List box [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796/Using-the-CListBox-control). You could define a member variable of type CListBox that is mapped to your list box via the control wizard.

Comment: I am using ListControl , not Listbox.